# Java code of AES/GCM/NoPadding encryption algorithm with authentication tag

Tags: java, android, ruby, encryption, aes

I am trying a ruby code convert in java but java code always gives javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: mac check in GCM failed. I have tried different java implementation from online but all of the solutions gives the same error. Any experts can help in this regards with proper code.
Here

Ruby Code:

```
gem 'openssl'
require 'openssl'
#iv: 151f64de7be34d15dacdaea9b33471f9 (hex)
#tag: 806bf2bbd3bf83cf1240b03e7c4d6ab1 (hex)
#data: 131b03571fc9ec47ef58e58e21fce5c10aa73a62b9e58a743bcdcc3aff1ea8ab
9964f4535b8597735f3da5f6ae63b9370625a20d633e9cf2986d4d118989124f
0ddfee956e47cb5cbc3617c520b075620b37ae4056f3a1af83351fda634dfb44
6055c75f7143a5600149db333893c0ecb0ef3944e2a64542e9a4375bf1526898
58fed8b21aded0eab0afb11190 (hex)
#key: 023aae7c450a283b23e3d7c1416ad644

# From Step 2
unwrapped_key = "\x02\x3a\xae\x7c\x45\x0a\x28\x3b\x23\xe3\xd7\xc1\x41\x6a\xd6\x44"

def decrypt_aes_gcm(key, iv, tag, data)
  decrypter = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('aes-128-gcm').decrypt
  decrypter.iv_len = 16
  decrypter.key = key
  decrypter.iv = iv
  decrypter.auth_tag = tag
  plaintext = decrypter.update(data) + decrypter.final
end

iv = "\x15\x1f\x64\xde\x7b\xe3\x4d\x15\xda\xcd\xae\xa9\xb3\x34\x71\xf9"
tag = "\x80\x6b\xf2\xbb\xd3\xbf\x83\xcf\x12\x40\xb0\x3e\x7c\x4d\x6a\xb1"
encrypted_data = "\x13\x1b\x03\x57\x1f\xc9\xec\x47\xef\x58\xe5\x8e\x21\xfc\xe5\xc1" + 
                 "\x0a\xa7\x3a\x62\xb9\xe5\x8a\x74\x3b\xcd\xcc\x3a\xff\x1e\xa8\xab" + 
                 "\x99\x64\xf4\x53\x5b\x85\x97\x73\x5f\x3d\xa5\xf6\xae\x63\xb9\x37" + 
                 "\x06\x25\xa2\x0d\x63\x3e\x9c\xf2\x98\x6d\x4d\x11\x89\x89\x12\x4f" + 
                 "\x0d\xdf\xee\x95\x6e\x47\xcb\x5c\xbc\x36\x17\xc5\x20\xb0\x75\x62" + 
                 "\x0b\x37\xae\x40\x56\xf3\xa1\xaf\x83\x35\x1f\xda\x63\x4d\xfb\x44" + 
                 "\x60\x55\xc7\x5f\x71\x43\xa5\x60\x01\x49\xdb\x33\x38\x93\xc0\xec" + 
                 "\xb0\xef\x39\x44\xe2\xa6\x45\x42\xe9\xa4\x37\x5b\xf1\x52\x68\x98" + 
                 "\x58\xfe\xd8\xb2\x1a\xde\xd0\xea\xb0\xaf\xb1\x11\x90"

plaintext = decrypt_aes_gcm(unwrapped_key, iv, tag, encrypted_data)

# plaintext = "\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x13\xe3\x60\x10\x9a" + 
#             "\xc1\xc8\xc1\x20\xc0\x20\x35\x91\x51\x48\xde\x35\x2f\xb9" + 
#             "\xa8\xb2\xa0\x24\x35\x45\xa1\x24\xb3\x24\x27\x95\x8b\x0b" + 
#             "\x21\x90\x94\x9f\x52\x29\x25\xc0\xc5\x02\x52\x0b\x54\x0d" + 
#             "\xa6\x35\x18\xc1\x22\x8c\x40\x11\x79\x29\x30\xad\xc1\x24" + 
#             "\x25\xc6\xc5\x01\x94\xfb\x0f\x04\xfc\x40\x75\x70\xb6\x92" + 
#             "\x0c\x97\x14\x97\xc0\xbb\x7f\x02\xb7\xa2\x2a\x9d\x55\x3b" + 
#             "\x76\xe5\x9e\x7a\xf4\x72\xfb\x1b\x21\x26\x0e\x79\x20\x66" + 
#             "\xd4\xe2\xe0\x10\x10\x02\x9a\x29\xc1\xa8\x05\xe2\xb1\x71" + 
#             "\xf0\x09\x31\x49\x30\x02\x00\xd1\x69\x5a\x2d\x9d\x00\x00\x00"
```

My Java Code:

```
 public static String decryptSymmetric128BitHexKeyUTF8(String ciphertext, String iv, String tag, String key) throws Exception {
        String algorithm = "AES/GCM/NoPadding";

        byte[] ciphertextBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(ciphertext);
        byte[] ivBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(iv);
        byte[] tagBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(tag);
        byte[] keyBytes = key.getBytes("UTF-8");

        // Fix: concatenate ciphertext and tag
        byte[] ciphertextTagBytes = new byte[ciphertextBytes.length + tagBytes.length]; 
        System.arraycopy(ciphertextBytes, 0, ciphertextTagBytes, 0, ciphertextBytes.length);
        System.arraycopy(tagBytes, 0, ciphertextTagBytes, ciphertextBytes.length, tagBytes.length);
        
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
        SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
        GCMParameterSpec gcmParameterSpec = new GCMParameterSpec(128, ivBytes);        
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, gcmParameterSpec);
        
        //boolean isAuth = cipher.getParameters().getParameterSpec(GCMParameterSpec.class).getIV() == 
        System.out.println("Key "+ (cipher.getParameters().getParameterSpec(GCMParameterSpec.class).getIV() == tagBytes));
        
        byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(ciphertextTagBytes);        
        return new String(decrypted, "UTF-8");
    }
```

Comment: All of your data is encoded in HEX. For the ciphertext, IV and GcmTag you decode them to bytes by "Base64.getDecoder().decode", the key is "decoded" by "getBytes". You need to decode all data by a "HexStringToBytes" decoding (you will find thousends of examples for this).

Comment: Additionally: The UTF-8 decoding at the end of the decryption corrupts the (non-UTF-8 compliant) data. Use a binary-to-text encoder, e.g. a hex encoder like [HexFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/en%2Fjava%2Fjavase%2F21%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java.base/java/util/HexFormat.html) (as of JDK 17). OT: For GCM a 12 bytes IV/nonce should be used for compatibility and performance reasons.